# appengine.googleapis: method() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm getting this error when I try to get the domain for my google app engine application using the rest API. It says the method() takes 1 arguments (2 given) can anyone help me?

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'secret.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

rest_service = discovery.build('appengine', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

@app.route('/audit/create', subdomain='<business>', methods=['GET'])
def audit_create(business):
    logging.debug(rest_service.apps().domainMappings().get('apps/branchify-dashboard/domainMappings/sample.branchify.co'))
    return render_template('audit/letsgetstarted.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add

> domainMappingsId

, parameter name to your argument list.

```
   rest_service.apps().domainMappings().get(domainMappingsId="apps/branchify-dashboard/domainMappings/sample.branchify.co")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue and made a medium article about this. For future people who would need this to work you can view it here: https://medium.com/@timothyouano/google-app-engine-custom-domains-getting-and-creating-them-progammatically-using-python-162f9c38ba4